# Django: how can I generate reverse urls including numbers in the string?

Tags: django

I´m using the following code to generate urls:

```
url(r'^productos/(?P<person_id>\D+)/$', views.ProductoView, name="producto"),
```

It works fine with strings that only have letters (dTape).

When I try a string that includes a number (d3Tape) I get a nonreverse error.

Any clues? Maybe my regex is not ok but I can´t find the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include all characters by using a character group that includes both `\d` and `\D`:

```
url(r'^productos/(?P<person_id>[\d\D]+)/$', views.ProductoView, name="producto"),
```

But I'm not sure if this is a good idea. It might be useful to restrict the caracters to a group, like:

```
url(r'^productos/(?P<person_id>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$', views.ProductoView, name="producto"),
```

this will include all ASCII alphanumerical characters and a hyphen and underscore.

In [django-2.x](/questions/tagged/django-2.x), I would advise to use the `str`, or `slug` path converters:

```
path('productos/<str:person_id>/', views.ProductoView, name="producto"),
```